# How to change skype profile name and picture using python skpy automatically

Tags: python, skype, skypedeveloper, skype-bots, skype4py

I would like to change the Skype user name and avatar using the python library [SkPy](https://skpy.t.allofti.me/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

https://skpy.t.allofti.me/api.html says the class Skype has a method setAvatar which is used to change your profile picture.  The link at the bottom, https://skpy.t.allofti.me/usage.html, gives you basic usage.

```
from skpy import Skype
from getpass import getpas
s = Skype(userId='fred.2')
s.setAvatar('path to your image')
```

I don't see a way to change your user name.